# Me cierra el terminal de node por error en el create del service de angular

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, angular5

Cuando guardo algo a la bd (MongoDB) desde la app, me cierra el servidor node en el terminal, sin embargo me guarda los datos.

Tengo en el archivo api_v1.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Profesor = require('../models/profesor');

router.post('/profesores', (req, res) => {
    delete req.body._id;
    Profesor.create(req.body, (err, Profesor) =>{
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }else{
            res.json(profesor);
        }
    });
});
```

En el terminal del navegador:

```
    Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js
Source Map URL: main.bundle.map[Learn More]
```

En la consola node dice:

```
C:\Users\leand\Documents\Universidad\Software III\PracticasProyecto\colegio-crud-app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

ReferenceError: profesor is not defined
    at Profesor.create (C:\Users\leand\Documents\Universidad\Software III\PracticasProyecto\colegio-crud-app\routes\api_v1.js:20:22)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leand\Documents\Universidad\Software III\PracticasProyecto\colegio-crud-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3954:16)...
```

Comment: la P no tendría que ser mayúscula? `res.json(Profesor);`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ocurre un error critico se para el servidor de node por error en la ejecución.
1º
Te guarda en base de datos porque el problema esta en la respuesta de la función no en la insercción en base de datos
2º
El error indica que la variable **profesor** no está definida, porque realmente no existe dicha variable y no puede parsear la respuesta a json de algo que no existe, la solución estaría en enviar  res.json(Profesor); **Profesor** es la promesa que devuelve el create.
Espero que esto le sirva. Un saludo